# Vectorize For Loops using Opencv C++

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, for-loop, optimization

My code has many "for" loops writing like this :

```
for (size_t img = 0; img!=m_nbofImage; img++) 
  {
     for (size_t i = 0; i!=image_size; i++) 
       {
          dataImg[img* image_size+i]=data_matImg[i];
        }
```

In order to increase the performance of my code, I want to use Opencv but I do not how.

In your opinion, how can I optimize this loop to increase performance?.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add the code needed to understand this snippet. What are dataImg and data_matImg supposed to be? What are you trying to achieve? What makes you think that this is slow? How much is "slow" for you? Have you profiled your code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying images pixels by pixels, you should copy the entire block using memcpy() for example. Whether this works depends on your variables type.

That said, if you want to use OpenCV, it has an optimized copy function copyTo(). By using it with masks and/or ROI, you should be able to copy images faster.